# Can't get div to show when unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

I am trying to use bootstrap toggle to create a switch to change between monthly and annual plans. I got the toggle to function in the sense it moves and looks right but I can not get the JS part to work. So it will only show the `monthly` div right now and will not switch to the annual div. Currently this is what I have

**Toggle**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-5"></div>
     <div class="col-md-4 selectCenter">
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" checked  id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Monthly" data-off="Annual" data-style="ios" data-onstyle="primary" data-offstyle="primary">
     </div>
   </div>
```

**Monthly div**

```
<section class="se-section" id="monthly">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
         <h1>Monthly</h1>
       </div> <!-- end col-md-4 -->
      </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->
  </section>
```

**Annual div**

```
<section class="se-section" id="annual">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
         <h1>Annual</h1>
       </div> <!-- end col-md-4 -->
      </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->
  </section>
```

**Then my javascript**

```
var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
var monthly = document.getElementById("monthly");
var annual = document.getElementById("annual");

if(toggle.checked){
  monthly.style.display = 'block';
  annual.style.display = 'none';
}
if(!toggle.checked){
  monthly.style.display = 'none';
  annual.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand a very basic concept in JavaScript, which is doing stuff when something else happens. In technical terms, binding to an event. You bind execution of some code (usually wrapped up in a function) every time some event happens:

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, options]);
```

- **type** is the event itself (its name)
- **listener** is the name of the function to be executed (you can have an anonymous function instead of a name, but it's better to keep it tidy and just put your code inside a named function
- **options** are:

  - *capture*: A Boolean indicating that events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.
  - *once*: A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.
  - *passive*: A Boolean indicating that the listener will never call preventDefault(). If it does, the user agent should ignore it and generate a console warning. See Improving scrolling performance with passive listeners to learn more.
  - *mozSystemGroup*: A Boolean indicating that the listener should be added to the system group. Available only in code running in XBL or in Firefox's chrome.

**options** is optional

Now, back to your example:

```
var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle"),
    monthly = document.getElementById("monthly"),
    annual = document.getElementById("annual");

// define functionality: 
function toggleDivs() {
   monthly.style.display = toggle.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
   annual.style.display = toggle.checked? 'none' : 'block';
}

// bind to `change` on toggle:
toggle.addEventListener('change', toggleDivs, {passive:true});

// bind to `window.onload` (so it runs once when the page is loaded):
window.onload = toggleDivs;
```

That's about it. Please note binding a function like this on `window.onload` is not exactly best practice (it can override another bind on it or can be overridden by a subsequent similar function). Read [this](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index.html) for details.

---

Alternatively, since you're using Bootstrap, it means you're also using jQuery, which enables a more concise syntax:

```
// define the function: 
function toggleDivs() {
  $('#monthly').css('display', $('#toggle').prop('checked') ?
    'block':'none');
  $('#weekly').css('display', $('#toggle').prop('checked') ?
    'none':'block');    
}
// bind to `change` on `#toggle` : 
$('#toggle').on('change', toggleDivs);

// bind to `load` on `window` :
$(window).on('load', toggleDivs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an EventListener to the toggle. The function assigned that way is going to be executed. This function shows then the correct block.

```
toggle.addEventListener('change', togglePlanViews);

function togglePlanViews() {
    if(toggle.checked){
      monthly.style.display = 'block';
      annual.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      monthly.style.display = 'none';
      annual.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript is actually only being executed once on page load.  So if you assigned one of them as 'checked' in the HTML to begin with, this would work.  However, nothing is checking whether or not these checkboxes are ticked or not afterwards.

Binding an event handler to an element will allow for this value to be checked again.  Most commonly, a button is used such as an 'Update' button but since you're using a checkbox, you can just tie one to a click event on the checkbox so it will be immediately evaluated whether or not it's checked.

So you need to tie that bit of code to an event such as a button click.  That can be done as such:

```
var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
var monthly = document.getElementById("monthly");
var annual = document.getElementById("annual");

toggle.addEventListener('click', function(){ //bind an anonymous function to a button click for the element referenced by 'toggle'
    if(toggle.checked){
        monthly.style.display = 'block';
        annual.style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(!toggle.checked){
        monthly.style.display = 'none';
        annual.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Now everytime someone clicks that checkbox, the value of the checkbox will be evaluated (checked or not) and will apply the proceeding effects to the style.

You can also abstract some of the details and create a named function that handles the checking and you can simply call the named function instead of an anonymous function upon the click event.

```
function checkTimeframe(){
    if(toggle.checked){
        monthly.style.display = 'block';
        annual.style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(!toggle.checked){
        monthly.style.display = 'none';
        annual.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
var monthly = document.getElementById("monthly");
var annual = document.getElementById("annual");

toggle.addEventListener('click', checkTimeframe);
```